# How to exclude certain element to be triggered by $(document).off('click')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable all click events except specific click on event on element.

```
 $(document).off('click');
```

Since it is disabling all the click events. I need to ignore it for certain element for example **.navbar-toggle**

Are there any way to exclude elements from this $(document).off('click')?

Comment: Are you trying to remove click events *you* have added? Or that a third party has added?

Comment: I just want to remove all click events except certain elements to be clicked. For example: It should ignore .navbar-toggle click

Comment: My question is who is in control of adding those events in the first place - you or not you?

Comment: Yes I am controlling it.

Comment: Maybe it's worth it giving a try to ... using the same selector which does target the `click` enabled elements and alter it slightly to `$('... :not(.navbar-toggle').off('click');`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger can you write your suggestion more precisely? I do not understand these dots ... Can write in the form of $(document).off('click') ?

Comment: @ShimolKhan ... As one did already suggest, edit the question and, since you are in control of the code, provide the part where all the elements are selected which later get registered with the event listener. This special selector/s then might be used in order to provide (an) altered version/s which target(s) all these elements again except for e.g the `.navbar-toggle` classified element/s.